# Help in writing a piecewise step function?

Tags: functions, recurrence-relations, exponential-function, ceiling-and-floor-functions, piecewise-continuity

I have the following step function I am working with:

[List of piecewise functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgNUe.png)

Upon plotting these, I realize I have a step function, specifically a floor function. Basically, for every power of 2, I use the function $$n^3 - n^2$$

For instance, values between 2 and 4 (exclusive) should equal 4, as $ 2^3 - 2^2 = 4$.

Similarly, values from 4 to 8 (exclusive) should equal 18, as $ 3^3 - 3^2 = 18$.

And finally, values from 8 to 16 (exclusive) should equal 48, as $ 4^3 - 4^2 = 18$.

For a range of values, namely up to but excluding what $ 2^n $ actually is, should equal $n^3 - n^2$ as the output. I've included a Desmos graph as well: [Desmos graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnFCP.png). I'm envisioning this to be a floor function but am just unsure of how to write it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution after playing around with logarithms in floor functions this morning! I believe it's

$$ f(x) = (\lfloor{lg (2x)}\rfloor)^3 -  (\lfloor{lg (2x)}\rfloor)^2$$ in which $ lg$ is the binary logarithm.